# Type keeps coming back null when calling GetType() for generic class

Tags: c#, .net

I am using this method,

```
Type typeArgument = Type.GetType(settingsType);
```

where settingsType is a string defined as

```
"XYZ.Program.Settings.ConcreteSettings`1[XYZ.Document.Locations.ConcreteLocation]"
```

and my class is defined like

```
namespace XYZ.Program.Settings
{
    public class ConcreteSettings<T> : ISettings<T> where T : ConcreteLocation
...
}
```

But the Concrete Location is in another project, which the above is referencing and it is defined like

```
namespace XYZ.Document.Locations
{
    public class ConcreteLocation : ILocation
    {
...

}
```

My Type keeps coming back as null.  I'm not sure how to solve this.

EDIT:  I was able to get my code to work using the string like this

```
"XYZ.Program.Settings.ConcreteSettings`1"
```

And then using this code

```
                var d1 =  Type.GetType(settingsType);
                Type[] typeArgs = { typeof(ConcreteLocation) };
                var makeme = d1.MakeGenericType(typeArgs);
                object o = Activator.CreateInstance(makeme);
```

I'm not sure the difference, or why using `1 without the type works

Comment: tried the overload Type.GetType which takes assembly and type resolver as callback? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee332932(v=vs.110).aspx. An easier way, try loading the ConcreteLocation class separately to ensure the type and corresponding assembly is loaded in app domain.

Comment: @gp. Ok thanks for the suggestion, I did find a way to get my code to work (see edit in original post)  I'm not sure if that's what you were suggesting.

Comment: You are loading a generic type without the type parameters. It's still fine. After you do typeof(ConcreteLocation), try loading your old type string (with the type) and see if that loads without needing MakeGenericType.

Comment: Have you tried a fully assembly qualified name for the classes? For example `XYZ.Program.Settings.ConcreteSettings\`1[XYZ.Document.Locations.ConcreteLocation, XYZ.Document], XYZ.Program`. Most likely `XYZ.Document.dll` hasn't been loaded yet, `GetType("XYZ.Document.Locations.ConcreteLocation")` won't work.